# Proving a statement about the sequences by contrapositive

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence with limit $L$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a_n\ge 0$ then $L\ge0$.

I know that we can prove that by choosing $\epsilon = \frac{|L|}{2}$ and showing there is no terms of the sequence in the $(L - \epsilon , L + \epsilon)$ interval but I wonder how to take the contrapositive of that statement and then proceed to prove. It seems we have two premises:

> $P : \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$
>
> $Q : \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \ \ a_n \ge0$

And the conclusion:

> $R : L\ge 0$

So the statement is $P \land Q  \implies R$ and the contrapositive is $\lnot R \implies \lnot P \ \lor \ \lnot Q$. Am I right about the taking contrapositive or not?

Comment: Yes you're right. Maybe the most critical part now is for you to write $\neg P$ in term of $\epsilon$ and so on.

Comment: Correct; it will be also $\lnot R \to (P \to \lnot Q)$ that amounts to : "if $L < 0$ then (if $\lim a_n=L$ then there is an $n$ such that $a_n < 0$)".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So if we suppose that $\lim a_n = L \lt 0$, then find an $n$ such that $a_n \lt 0$, can we conclude that the statement is proven?